# Give an example for which $\sigma (S \cap T) \neq \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T). $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

If $S$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, we denote by $\sigma(S)$ the smallest $\sigma-$ algebra that contains $S.$

Give an example for which $\sigma (S \cap T) \neq \sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T). $

And I have read the following answer online:

Let $S$ be the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}.$
Let $B$ be the collection of Borel measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}.$
Let $T = S\setminus B \neq \emptyset$ this is because we have a measurable set , a subset of Borel set, that is not a Borel set.

Then the answer said that, then $S\cap T = \emptyset$(which I donot understand at all) and that $\sigma (S \cap T) = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$(which I do not understand why?)And the answer said that also $\sigma(S) \cap \sigma(T) = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$(which I do not understand also)

Could anyone explain for me the points I do not understand, it seems to me the example is wrong or lacking details? it is greatly appreciated if I received a correction for this example.

Comment: I they define $T=S\setminus B$, they have $S\cap T=\emptyset$ only when $S\subseteq B$ (and so $T=\emptyset$), And if they arrive at $\sigma(S\cap T)=\sigma(S)\cap \sigma(T)$, this does not look like a counterexample.

Comment: yes Borel sets @saz I am sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{O}$ denote the set of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ denote the set of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, it is classical that $\sigma(\mathcal{O})=\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),$ with the latter denoting the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Accordingly $\sigma(\mathcal{C})\cap \sigma(\mathcal{O})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

However, $\mathcal{O}\cap \mathcal{C}=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\},$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, so $\mathcal{O}\cap\mathcal{C}$ already is a $\sigma$-algebra, and hence $\sigma(\mathcal{O}\cap \mathcal{C})=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$. This clearly isn't the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Or, more general (so we do not always get the Borel algebra), let $\mathcal O$ be any non-trivial collection of subsets with $A\in \mathcal O\to A^\complement\notin \mathcal O$, and let $\mathcal C=\{\,A^\complement\mid A\in\mathcal O\,\}$. Then clearly $\sigma(\mathcal O)=\sigma(\mathcal(T)$ (and nontrivial) whereas $S\cap T=\emptyset$.

Comment: This definitely also works.

Comment: what is $T$?@HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 2):

Simpler (and more correct) example: Let $S$ be the set of all open  intervals with rational endpoints and $T$ the set of open intervals with irrational endpoints. Then clearly $S\cap T=\emptyset$ and so $\sigma(S\cap T)=\{\emptyset,\Bbb R\}$ (which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra at all). On the other hand, $\sigma(S)\cap\sigma(T)$ is much larger as for example $$(\sqrt 2,\sqrt3)\in T\subseteq \sigma(T)$$ and also $$(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)=\bigcup_{\sqrt 2<a<b<\sqrt 3\atop a,b\in\Bbb Q }(a,b)\in \sigma(S).$$
(Bonus: Do you see why in fact $\sigma(S)=\sigma(T)$ and which well-known algebra that is?)

Comment: I can see that there is an intersection between the 2 types of intervals you suggested, for example, $(1,2) \cap (\sqrt {2}, \sqrt{3}) =(\sqrt {2}, \sqrt{3}) $  ..... what is your opinion?

Comment: For the answer to your bonus, no I can not see why  the 2 sigma algebras are equal maybe it is the Borel one

Comment: It seems like I do not understand thoroughly your definition for $S$ and $T$, I know that between any 2 rational numbers there is an irrational number and also between any 2 irrational numbers there is a rational number.

Comment: Could you please prove the line before last in your answer?